# Inserting empty character into snprintf

Tags: c, ternary-operator

Defines:

- **CHAR_BACKSLASH** is defined as '\\' or 0x5C

Variables:

- **workingDir** is a C-String
- **myFilePath** is a C-String

  ```
  int len = strlen(workingDir);
  char lastChar = workingDir[len - 1];
  ```

Below, **myFilePath** gets formed from **workingDir** + *a backslash* + the literal *"myfile.txt"*

In the ternary argument, I'm trying to put a backslash if there is not already a backslash.

```
    snprintf(myFilePath,
             sizeof(myFilePath),
             "%s%s%s",
             workingDir,
             (lastChar == CHAR_BACKSLASH) ? "" : "\\",
             "myfile.txt");
```

If possible, I would like to change it to something like this, but not sure how, because it requires an empty single-quote char and I'm not sure if that's allowed.

```
    snprintf(myFilePath,
             sizeof(myFilePath),
             "%s%c%s",
             workingDir,
             (lastChar == CHAR_BACKSLASH) ? '' : CHAR_BACKSLASH,
             "myfile.txt");
```

Comment: The first case is clearer as to what the intent is. The last case is less clear, and very likely snprintf is only slightly fasters at processing chars than strings of length one. The optimization is not worth the lack of readablity.

Comment: What if I changed it to using '\\' for clarity, instead of the hex code in all cases?

Comment: You have a good point.  I changed it to using a define (CHAR_BACKSLASH) for clarity, instead of the hex code for backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this? Then you don't have to worry about whether '' is a valid case for %c. And snprintf has one less varg to process.

```
snprintf(myFilePath,
         sizeof(myFilePath),
         (lastChar == '\\') ? "%s%s" : "%s\\%s"
         workingDir,
         "myfile.txt");
```

Comment: I like this solution.  I didn't think of doing the ternary operator on the format string itself.  Smart!